# Why doesn't work Paperclip interpolations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip, interpolation

I am trying to make work Paperclip interpolations the whole afternoon, but still not success.

Here is how I have set up the **Image** model:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => { :thumb => '300x300#', 
                                 :medium => "300x300>", 
                                 :original => "900x900>" },

                    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :url => "/images/:user_id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

In **/config/initializers/paperclip.rb** is following:

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"

```
module Paperclip
    module Interpolations
        def user_id attachment, style_name
            attachment.instance.user_id.to_s
        end
    end
end
```

But every time I save a file, the files is saved as

```
/images//original/file-name.jpg
```

The user's ID is missing.

What is wrong in this sample? I still cannot find the right config of Paperclip setup. I would be very grateful for every help.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the object has user_id present? Can you provide some Image object present?

Comment: What do you mean that user_id is present?

Comment: If the `user_id` attribute of the `image` object is null, then the url will not contain the corresponding value.

Comment: hmm... (1) I would test via Rails console to make sure properly associated (2) try changing the name of the paperclip interpolation to something else like user_id_val

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in your Image model

```
Paperclip.interpolates :user_id do |attachment, style|
   attachment.instance.user_id.to_s
end
```

Comment: I just tried it and the same... the `user_id` part is still empty

Comment: are you sure that an image is associated correctly with a user? Can you attach via Rails console?